# when does a file check in linux fail

Tags: shell, sh

I am using a check `-f` in my code to see if a particular file is present.

I suspect that sometimes (maybe in 1 out of 10 cases) it doesn't work as I see some strange errors in that situation.

the code I have is: `if [-f /folder/file] do something
else remove something`.

in my deployment, /folder/file is always present. so the above file check should always work, but I see in some very rare cases that remove something gets called instead...which is not right. remove something should not get called if the above /folder/file is present.

if /folder/file is present, are there cases where a -f check can still fail? like for instance if either the folder or file is read only or based on permissions??

Comment: That's not valid code. `[-f` is not a valid command and you're missing semicolons and you're missing `then` and `fi`.

Comment: Probably there is some error in the code that you didn't show us. No, the `-f` check always works well.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a space after the `[`! Between `[` and `-f`

```
if [ -f  "/folder/file" ] ; then
  echo "do something"
else 
  echo "do something else"
fi
```